# Problems connecting Samsung mobile phone

Tags: usb, drivers, mobile-phone, kies

I have [Samsung GT-E1200](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/mobile-phones/bar/GT-E1200ZKABTU) and I am trying to connect it via USB cable to my PC. I looked at  the Samsung page http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-E1200ZKABTU-downloads for available drivers/software and all I found there is Kies, so I installed the newest version onto my Windows 7 system.

The problem is that when I run Kies and connect the device, I get the Windows tray message: "USB device not recognized", and Kies also does not see the device. In Kies I tried to use some tool which should fix the problem with connecting devices (by installing new drivers), but it didn't help. Neither after several restarts of Kies and Windows, and updates to both Windows and Kies.

Comment: You might want to try another USB cable if you haven't already. The one that came with my old Samsung phone worked unreliably for data (but fine for charging). Yet, this same cable worked fine for data with a number of other devices.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be caused by a faulty USB cable, a faulty port in your device - or an incorrect USB mode selected on your device. Please explain what are you trying to achieve (ie. mount the device as USB drive, as a wireless modem or a network tethering device?).

Comment: the cable is just new, the ports are OK (I've tried different ones). *" incorrect USB mode selected on your device"* -- which device you mean? I am trying to transfer SMS and Contacts to my PC.

Comment: On a second thought... I'm not sure if this phone supports any active USB connectivity. From what I see over the net, the USB port is only for charging the phone :( ([source](http://www.mgsm.pl/pl/katalog/samsung/gte1200/) - no USB data transmission)

Comment: Great, thanks @Michał ! Please would you know how to find out the same for LG CE0168? Cannot find it on the page you posted nor at lg.com.